# data of last 4 quarter

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to fetch data of last 4 quarter including current quarter.
Suppose if I run the query on `30-MAR-2019` then I want data from `01-APR-2018` to `31-MAR-2019`
and if I run the query on `01-apr-2019` then I want data between `01-JUL-2018` and `30-JUN-2019`

Could you please help me on the same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select (trunc(sysdate, 'Q') + interval '3' month) as next_quarter_start,
       (trunc(sysdate, 'Q') + interval '15' month) - interval '1' day as next_quarter_end 
from dual;
```

Comment: could you please me to remove syntax error as well? above query is not running.

Comment: @OnkarTiwari . . . There is no syntax error.  This was tested before I posted it, and here is the evidence:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7ff04a37ab269279447ea679b900c20b.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - actually there was an error in the code posted here. I corrected `interval '1 day'` to  `interval '1' day`. You're welcome ;-)

Comment: not getting desired result. I have to fetch first date of first quarter and last date of 4th quarter. If i run the query today so last day of current quarter is 30-JUN-2019 and first date of previous 3 quarter is 01-JUL-2018......we have to select data of 4 quarter including current quarter

Comment: @OnkarTiwari . . . Just change the ending date by adding more months.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select TRUNC(sysdate+1, 'Q') - interval '9' month,TRUNC(sysdate+1, 'Q') + 
interval '3' month -1
from dual  ;

01-JUL-2018 30-JUN-2019

select TRUNC(to_date('30-MAR-2019')+1, 'Q') - interval '9' 
month,TRUNC(to_date('30-MAR-2019')+1, 'Q') + interval '3' month -1
from dual  ;

01-APR-2018 31-MAR-2019
```

Comment: it is giving result of 5 quarter.......suppose if I am running query today(16-APR-2019) then result should be 01-JUL-2018 to 30-JUN-2019.  if I am running on 30-MAR-2019 then result should be 01-APR-2018 to 31-MAR-2019.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is getting the last day of the quarter.

This solution calculates the starting day of the range by subtracting 9 months from the target date and then truncating with the `'Q'` mask which gives us the first day of the quarter. We then calculate that date *again*, subtract one day then add twelve months and that gives the last day of the current quarter:

```
with tgt as ( select date '2019-03-30' as dt from dual
              union all select date '2019-02-28' as dt from dual
              union all select date '2019-04-01' as dt from dual
)
select trunc(tgt.dt - interval '9' month, 'Q') as range_st,
       (trunc(tgt.dt - interval '9' month, 'Q') - 1) + interval '12' month as range_end
from tgt
/
```

There may be a slicker solution out there, but this is the end of my coffee break :)

Answer (score 0):

This is dynamically:

```
With param as (
  Select 
    to_date(extract(year from add_months(sysdate,-12)) || 
            lpad((floor(extract(month from add_months(sysdate,-12))/3)*3)+1,2, '0') || '01', 
            'yyyymmdd') first_date 
    from dual
)
Select 
  level                                               quartal,
  Add_months(first_date, ((level-1)*3))               from_dat,
  Last_day(add_months(first_date, ((level-1)*3)+3)-1) to_dat
From param
connect by level <= 4;
```